# Return error messages on rest call in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5, http-post

I have to receive a POST request from a client to my REST app in laravel 5. I'm follow the documentation related to validation, it said that when is an AJAX request laravel do not generate a redirect response, instead it will generate a JSON response with errors(https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields). But when I make the call from a REST client I'm getting this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://laraveltest.com:8080/test/public" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://laraveltest.com:8080/test/public</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://laraveltest.com:8080/test/public">http://laraveltest.com:8080/test/public</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

AdultoPost class *********************

```
class AdultoPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Profesion' => "max:50",
            "EstadoCivil" => "required",
            "FamiliaReconstituida" => "required",
            "SolteroConHijo" => "required",
            "Viudo" => "required",
            "NoHijos" => "required"
        ];
    }
}
```

AdultoController **************

```
 public function post(AdultoPost $request, Adulto $adulto, Paciente $paciente, Persona $persona)
        {
            $persona = Persona::create($request->all());
            $adulto = Adulto::create($request->all());
            $paciente = Paciente::create($request->all());
return $adulto;
    }
```

If I change AdultoPost class for Request and put the validation rules inside the post function and catch a ValidationException I get this error response  "The given data was invalid". Which is not what I want. I would like to send to the client which fields were invalid and why.

I'm making the request from REST API plugin of VSCODE, and from REST API TESTING extension from chrome, and now I'm installing POSTMAN to continue testing

```
POST http://laraveltest.com:8080/test/public/api/adulto
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "FechaInicio":"2017-09-10",
    "MotivoConsulta":"un motivo real",
    "ComoConocio":"como conocio"
}
```

Comment: Please specify how do you make request to your REST api. If you're doing ajax, you can check on your console the actual data structure sent by your api, but if you're not using ajax then please provide your code on your html forms and the actual function code that handles your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you make request from a client. Be sure to set correct headers, so it's a valid JSON request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Curl example:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost/api
```

Comment: Added Accept: application/json, but still getting the same problem

Comment: In you updated question I can see only `Content-type`. I just tested my api endpoint and it only need `Accept: application/json`. `'Content-type` won't work.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I was going crazy. I have to remove Content-type!!! Then add Accept: application/json, because the two at the same time isn't working!!!